# AngularJs routing delay and mobile application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I am using AngularJs to make a PhoneGap application.

I have 4 pages. And I am using angular-route to  make it a single page application.

But the problem is the delay of requesting each page it is not a good experience for the users. Is there any tricky solution for this problem ?

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .when('/view', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/view.html'
        })
        .when('/view/:idType/:movieID', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/view.html'
        })
        .when('/results/:queryType/:query', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/results.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        })

}]);
```

Comment: What is being requested? When you say "each page", do you mean the template, the data, or both?

Comment: @m58 the template of each page when visiting it using ajax

Comment: My site is fast with rendering the views with AngularJS. It is a bit slow with my images since they are so large. I just haven't dealt with formatting my photos. You can check it out at www.programmingpat.com and see if it is comparable.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by "the delay of requesting each page" there are several things you can do to optimize your loading times but few specific to angular, you just need to follow responsive design/progressive enhancement rules and your templates should load just fine, now you can always use $templateCache service to keep your templates in a single JS file, if you are using resolve clauses on your routes, make sure the delays are not on the apis, also make sure you don't perform extensive loops that might block your ui during controller creation that might give the impression of slow loading, can you check  your network tab and make share your API and templates loading times for more detailed information?